# Performance map and reject VS reject while mapping

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have an array of objects where each object responds to the method id. Let's call it `arr_to_proces`  And I have another array of ids. Let's call `ids_to_not_consider`

I want to get a set of `ids` from the `arr_to_proces`, rejecting the ones that are within the `ids_to_not_consider` array.

My first approach is this:

```
arr_to_proces.map(&:id) - ids_to_not_consider
```

So, I map and then I substract. Is there a more performant way of doing this in Ruby?

Comment: How big are `arr_to_process` and  `ids_to_not_consider`?

Comment: I have a feeling that your actual processing is going to dwarf any possible performance pennies you might be able to save here.

Comment: They might be something between 3000 and 5000 both.

@SergioTulentsev care to explain more?

Comment: It depends on the size of both arrays. Maybe ordering the arrays and consider only the first `ids_to_not_consider` when rejecting could help.

Comment: @HommerSmith: I mean, have you identified this to be a performance problem? How?

Comment: 3-5k sounds not that big for this kind of operation. Putting the arrays into Sets could be another option, `ids_to_not_consider = Set.new(ids_to_not_consider)`.